# Php recursively read files matching a pattern from all subfolders

Tags: javascript, php

I have a directory with multiple folders.

Each folder has a file ***index.html***.

The absolute path of index.html is something like:

`C:\Users\Sachin_S2\Desktop\Script\ESXi_6.7_GSG_Pub=9=Validator (XXXX)=en-us\index.html`

The above path can be interpreted as:

`[Any_folder_location\Script\<Pub_title>=<Pub_version>=Validator (XXXX)=en-us\index.html]`

The pub title here is: **ESXi_6.7_GSG_Pub** and Pub version here is: **9**

Now, i want to read all the files in the subfolder with following conditions (or patterns):

**1)** Read only index.html's (across all the subfolders)

**2)** Search the filepath for **Pub_Title** and **Pub_Version**

**3)** Read only those files

To give an example.

Below is the folder structure.

[image]

My current script :

```
<?php
$it = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator("C:\Users\Sachin_S2\Desktop\Script");
foreach(new RecursiveIteratorIterator($it) as $file) {
    echo $file . "<br/> \n";

}
```

Script outputs:

[image]

Basically i want to read all index.htmls which searches for pubtitle and pubversion.

Cases:

An index.html with ESXi_6.7_GSG_Pub and version 9

An index.html with ESXi_6.7_GSG_Pub and version 8

An index.html with ESXi_6.5_IIG_Pub and version 13
 etc

Comment: `explode("\\Script\\", $file)` will give you the path `ESXi_6.7_GSG_Pub=9=Validator`. From there, you could use `explode()` again with `_Pub=` to check for a pub version.

Comment: Does `Pub_Title` always has the same name/format? Or at least some common pattern or `ESXi...`?

Comment: No `Pub_Title` and `Pub_Version` keeps varying..

Comment: Eh, that makes things more complicated. Is the location always the same. As in will it always be located in `Scripts`?

Comment: As of now in my local, yea, its `Scripts`

Comment: Is there any common element for this string `<Pub_title>=<Pub_version>=Validator (XXXX)=en-us`? Perhaps `Validator` is present in all these titles? Or maybe the format itself, like pub title followed by an equal sign followed by version followed by equal etc etc.

Comment: Yea, the format is always common, only the `Pub_Title` and `Pub_Version` changes. Everything else is the same

Comment: Ah, now we're getting somewhere.

Comment: Could you please suggest a snippet for this? @Andrei

Answer (score 0):

This is the best I could come up with the information given.
Next time do consider posting some of your own efforts too to speed things up. 2 heads are always better than one.

I've mimicked your folder structure locally and I've ended up with something like this:

```
- SomeFolderName 
  - ESXI_6.7GSG_PUB=9=Validator (things)=en-us
     - index.html // contains "index 1"
  - ESXI_6.9GSG_PUB=9=Validator (things)=en-us
     - index.html // contains "index 2"
```

This is obviously dummy data structure and I don't expect it to match fully.

With that in mind the next thing would be to traverse the folders, you've done that yourself in the question.

```
function recursiveDirectoryIterator($path)
{
    $indexContent = [];

    foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path)) as $file) {
        if ($file->isDir() && preg_match('/(=[0-9]=)/', $file->getPath())) {
            if (file_exists($file->getPath().'/index.html')) {
                $indexContent[$file->getPath()] = file_get_contents($file->getPath().'/index.html');
            }
        }
    }

    return $indexContent;
}

var_dump(recursiveDirectoryIterator('../SomeFolderName'));
```

Locally this gives me

```
array(2) {
  ["../SomeFolderName/Script/ESXI_6.7GSG_PUB=9=Validator (things)=en-us"]=>
  string(7) "index 1"
  ["../SomeFolderName/Script/ESXI_6.9GSG_PUB=9=Validator (things)=en-us"]=>
  string(7) "index 2"
}
```

You'll also notice that I'm using a very very simple regex `/(=[0-9]=)/`. It will simply look for an equal sign followed by a number followed by an equal sign.

---

I don't expect this to be a full solution but I do hope it puts you on the right track.

Comment: I am getting only single array like `array(1) { ["C:\Users\Sachin_S2\Desktop\Script\ESXi_6.7_GSG_Pub=9=Validator (Dell)=en-us"]=> string(16071) " "} ` and also it displays the html output on the screen. uh?